# C# How to break out of a nested for loop and continue with a new loop?

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop, foreach, unity-game-engine

I am making a quest system for my game in Unity2D. I stored all my different kind of quests inside a dictionary but only 5 quests to be picked randomly for the player. I used nested loops first to get 5 random numbers, and then another foreach loop to access the elements inside the dictionary and lastly planned to use another for loop to print out all the picked quests. However, I am having problem because it printed out 25times, instead of 5. Is there a way to break out of the 2nd loop and go into the 3rd loop? Thanks!

```
void Start()
{
    // missions
    missions.Add("Visit Mural Stops x ", 1);
    missions.Add("Collect Cards x ", 2);
    missions.Add("Fight Monsters x", 3);
    missions.Add("Collect Coins x ", 4);
    missions.Add("Collect Items x", 5);
    missions.Add("Fight SBM Boss x ", 6);
    missions.Add("Find Mural Stops  x", 7);

    var numbers = new List<int>(missions.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < missions.Count; i++)
    {
        numbers.Add(i);
    }

    var randomNumbers = new int[text.Length];
    // text.Length is always 5, as I only have 5 mission texts

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.Length; i++)
    {
        var thisNumber = Random.Range(1, numbers.Count);
        randomNumbers[i] = numbers[thisNumber];
        numbers.RemoveAt(thisNumber);
        //Debug.Log("random " + randomNumbers[i]);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pairs in missions)
        {
            if (pairs.Value == randomNumbers[i])
            {
                //Debug.Log(pairs.Key); // print out 5 missions

                missionText = pairs.Key;

                for (int j = 0; j < text.Length; j++)
                {
                    text[j].text = missionText; // it only print out the last picked quests
                    Debug.Log(missionText); // each picked quest is printed out 5 times instead of once
                    // how do i print out only 5 times inside this loop?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its almost as if you have to [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) out of the loop...

Comment: What is your last loop meant to be doing? You loop on j but then never actually use j which makes no sense. You are just telling it to print out 5 times which is presumably why you are getting it five times as much as you want...

Comment: @maccettura i tried putting a break before  for (int j = 0; j < text.Length; j++), but nothing is printed out!

Comment: @Chris hey I want to print all the picked quests into my texts, text[j].text = missionText;

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your last loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < text.Length; j++)
{
    text[j].text = missionText;
    Debug.Log(missionText);
}
```

This is running the `Debug.Log` five times - once for each value of j (and you say earlier that `text.Length` is always 5).

In comments you say want to print all the picked quests into my texts.

You already have an index for your text - `i` - since your `randomNumbers` array is the same length as your texts and indeed the whole point of `randomNumbers` seems to be to generate a random number for each entry of `text`. So rather than that loop I quoted what you want to do is:

```
text[i].text = missionText;
```

Comment: ah! thanks! That works, I didn't thought about that haha! thanks  for suggestion :)